# Why are structure functions the same type as ordinary functions

Tags: go, struct

In following codes:
type of `struct Struct.Test` is `void func()`, the function can get all parameters in `Struct t`, why the types of `Struct.func()` and `func()` are the same

```
type Struct struct {
    Val string
}

func (t *Struct) Test() {
    println(t.Val)
}

func main() {
    t := Struct{
        Val: "Struct",
    }
    f := t.Test
    f()
    f = func() {
        println("Hello world!")
    }
    f()
}
```

Comment: Both the function and the method have the same signature, namely `()` (i.e. no input params and no output params).

Comment: That's some variant of currying which is common in most modern langauges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.Test` is a [method value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values):

> If the expression `x` has static type `T` and `M` is in the method set of type `T`, `x.M` is called a *method value*. **The method value `x.M` is a function value that is callable with the same arguments as a method call of `x.M`.** The expression `x` is evaluated and saved during the evaluation of the method value; the saved copy is then used as the receiver in any calls, which may be executed later.

The `x.Test()` method has no parameters, so `x.Test` is a function without parameters. The receiver `x` is saved internally and used when you call the `x.Test` function value later. Its type will be `func()`, so type of `f` is also `func()`, to which you can assign any value that also has a type of `func()`.

Don't confuse method values with [method expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions):

> If `M` is in the method set of type `T`, `T.M` is a function that is callable as a regular function with the same arguments as `M` prefixed by an additional argument that is the receiver of the method.

The method expression is "applied" on a *type*, while a method value is "applied" on a *value*. Method expression results in a function value that includes the receiver type (as the first parameter), method value does not (the receiver is saved internally).

So in your case the method expression would be `(*Struct).Test` (note the pointer: `Test()` has pointer receiver), and it's a function with type `func(Struct)`. It may be used / called like this:

```
f2 := (*Struct).Test
f2(&t)
```

Which again outputs `Struct`, try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/hKvNfFwwjt5).